# How to access a razor component from one razor page to another razor page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, blazor

I am looking for a way to access a razor component from one razor page to another razor page

Example,

Parent Razor Page (A) contains a razor component (B) that is provided a page directive for another page (C), which contains a razor component (D). A should contain B which should only contain D component from page C. How is it possible to achieve? I am looking for referencing rendered D with data from C. how will this changes if D is a HTML div rather than a razor component?

Already Tried:

I had initially an iframe inside B to open C as a rendered html webpage but that was messing up with dialog boxes of D that opens up as modal in C.

I also tried using cascading parameters and cascading values but didn't have any luck.

I also tried using jquery to load the HTML and replace it with the first html tag of B but that gave me an error saying "Blazor is already running"

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: As mentioned

"Already Tried:

I had initially an iframe inside B to open C as a rendered html webpage but that was messing up with dialog boxes of D that opens up as modal in C.

I also tried using cascading parameters and cascading values but didn't have any luck.

I also tried using jquery to load the HTML and replace it with the first html tag of B but that gave me an error saying "Blazor is already running""

Comment: You can't pass around instances of components.  You need to be a little clearer and produce some form of [mre] that demonstrates what you want.  What does Component D do?  I'm sure its possible, but we [people who answer questions] need to understand the problem.   I'm guessing you want to display the same information in both page A and C.  But that's a guess!  What you almost certainly need to do is share state.   The instances of D in A and C are different instances but share the same state data.